# photoshop pixels to android density-independent pixels

Tags: java, android

I am working on poster maker application  so  I having photoshop template and  trying to set exact same design in my android device through dynamic coding which  look like photoshop template , I have that design in parts like images of that design ,texts of that design is different part so user can rearrange it,
My Question :
I have that design parts x axis ,y axis in px  and I have to set in dp,
I tried to convert x and y axis px value to dp value,

> DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

> ```
>  int brandx = Math.round(51.189f * (displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
>
>  int brandy = Math.round(27.985f * (displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
> ```

For set one image part through above code but it not came on position,

Help me out on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the second answer there, the one with 130+ upvotes, not the accepted one on top.

Comment: @GabeSechan that answer convert dip to px and i want to convert px to dp

Comment: Just swap the constants.  The function is bidirectional.  Also dip and dp are the same thing.